# JsonValidationError is not an object error interpretation

Tags: json, scala, playframework, lagom

Does any one have any idea what the cause of this error might be?

```
Future(
  Success(
    JsError(
      List(
        (,List(
            JsonValidationError(
              List(
                [{"FIELD1":"field1value","FIELD2":"field2value","FIELD3":"field3value"}] is not an object
              ),
              ArraySeq())
))))))
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE** The code that generated this output looks like:

```
val queryResponse: Future[JsResult[MyObject]] = ws.url(queryURL)
    .withCookies(cookies.toSeq :_*)
    .get().map{response =>
    (response.json \ "object").validate[MyObject]
  }
```

The response coming from the server seems to be a list of JSON objects.

MyObject structure looks like:

```
case class MyObject(
                    FIELD1: Int,
                    FIELD2: Int,
                    FIELD3: String,
                    FIELD4: String,
                    FIELD5: String,
                    FIELD6: Int,
                    FIELD7: String,
                    FIELD8: String,
                    FIELD9: Option[String],
                    FIELD10: String,
                    FIELD11: String,
                    FIELD12: String,
                    FIELD13: Int
                  )

object MyObject
{

  implicit val format: Format[MyObject] = Json.format

  implicit val myObjectWrites = Json.writes[MyObject]

  implicit val myObjectReads: Reads[MyObject] = (
    (JsPath \ "FIELD1").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "FIELD2").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "FIELD3").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "FIELD4").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "FIELD5").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "FIELD6").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "FIELD7").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "FIELD8").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "FIELD9").readNullable[String] and
      (JsPath \ "FIELD10").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "FIELD11").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "FIELD12").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "FIELD13").read[Int])(MyObject.apply _)

}
```

Comment: Do you know what is the response came from server where you sent the request? It seems like JSON validation failed in `object` field. Please, share also `MyObject` structure.

Comment: @IvanKurchenko please see addition to my post. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the response JSON from which came server  for the request which gave this error?

Comment: You are defining Reads and Writes twice for `MyObject` -- a `Format` is a `Reads` & `Writes`.

Comment: @IvanKurchenko the Future response looks something like this:
`Future(Success(JsError(List((,List(JsonValidationError(List([{"FIELD1":"1","FIELD2":"1","FIELD3":"field3","FIELD4":"field4","FIELD5":"field5","FIELD6":"field6","FIELD7":"field7","FIELD8":"field8","FIELD9":null,"FIELD10":"field10","FIELD11":"field11","FIELD12":"field12","FIELD13":"field13"}] is not an object),ArraySeq())))))))
`

Comment: And the output without validation (just raw from the server) reads:
`Future(Success(JsUndefined([{"FIELD1":"1","FIELD2":"1","FIELD3":"field3","FIELD4":"field4","FIELD5":"field5","FIELD6":"field6","FIELD7":"field7","FIELD8":"field8","FIELD9":null,"FIELD10":"field10","FIELD11":"field11","FIELD12":"field12","FIELD13":"field13"}] is not an object)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to parse an object from a JSON document which looked like this:

```
{
  "object": [
    { "FIELD1":"field1value","FIELD2":"field2value","FIELD3":"field3value"}
  ]
}
```

Instead, use

```
(response.json \ "object" \ 0).validate[MyObject]
```

or

```
(response.json \ "object").validate[Seq[MyObject]]
```

Here is a scastie snippet to illustrate: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/avdv/gNc2SFkIR2ukvDtr7ZiYJw

Comment: Thank @cbley. The former errored out in run time with a recipient actor didn't send a reply error. And the latter issued an "implicit not found error" and compile time.

Comment: @bigsky You are probably doing something wrong. Show your complete code and JSON.

Comment: The JASON is provide above in my comment to @Ivan. The line of code that generates this error looks like:
`val queryResponse = ws.url(queryURL) 
    .withCookies(cookies.toSeq :_*)
    .get().map{response =>
    (response.json \ "myObject" \ 0).validate[MyObject]
  }`

Comment: @B That's only the partial JSON. Please show the full JSON, ie. the value of `response.json`.

Comment: @BigSky did you have a look at the scastie snippet? Paste your JSON in there and report back any errors.

Comment: Hi @cbley. OK, I seem to have had a misunderstanding about how to read in the json. The output of the response.json looks like `Future(Success([{"FIELD1":"field1","FIELD2":"field1","FIELD3":"field3","FIELD4":"field4","FIELD5":"field5","FIELD6":"field6","FIELD7":"field7","FIELD8":"field8","FIELD9":null,"FIELD10":"field10","FIELD11":"field11","FIELD12":"field12","FIELD13":"field13"}]))` No errors this time. So my question now is how to convert that into "MyObject" scala object?

Comment: @bigsky Um, you printed the whole Future somehow... that's still not the JSON document. You can print the JSON with `println(Json.prettyPrint(response.json))`. Did you look at the scastie snippet? Try to experiment with it by pasting your JSON into the triple quotes. Share the link to the changed snippet if anything is unclear and ask specific questions.

Comment: @cleb, sorry I am quite new to a lot of this. Thank you for your patience. Here is the scastie link: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1TZ9m9rsTuezdZ6hQjb8zA. My specific question: How do I map this output, which is generally a list of JSON objects, into MyObject scala class? Thank you so much for your patience!

Comment: Something is not quite right, you modeled `FIELD1`, `FIELD2`, `FIELD6` and `FIELD13` as an integer, but in your JSON it's a simple String... I don't know which one is the truth, so I changed the case class to match the data. Here is the updated snippet: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/2ZHPBlhGS1Gk6AwjHBq6yA

Comment: Thank you. That indeed did fix the problem. All good now. Thanks, again!